# Параметризированный SQL запрос

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть запрос который делает определённую выборку. Вот запрос:

```
select da.act_year||' - '|| da.act_number act_id,
       da.pipe_number,
       DA.DIAMETER,
       da.wall,
       da.steel,
       da.pipe_length pipe_len,
       da.pipe_weigth pipe_wei, 
       da.pipe_year,
       sr.id||' - '||sr.select_description prich_perev, 
       act_date,smena,
       (select FIO from intershop.auth_users where user_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(master_id, '^.*\\', null) and rownum = 1) FIO_Master,
       (select FIO from intershop.auth_users where user_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(inspector_id, '^.*\\', null) and rownum = 1) FIO_Inspector
from   DEFECT_ACTS da 
left   join Sel_Rjs2 sr 
on     da.id_prich_perev = sr.ID
where  DA.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    (da.act_number >= :act_begin or :act_begin1 is null)
and    (da.act_number <= :act_end or :act_end1 is null)
and    (da.Diameter = :diam or :diam1 is null)
and    (da.wall = :wall or :wall1 is null)
and    (da.id_prich_perev = :prich_perev or :prich_perev1 is null)
and    (da.act_year = :act_year_ or :act_year_1 is null)
and    da.act_date between :DATA_START and :DATA_END 
and    (da.pipe_number = :p_n or :p_n1 is null)
and    (da.pipe_year = :p_e or :p_e1 is null)   
order  by act_number desc
```

Если все параметры `null` тогда нечего не выдаст. Если задать даты между которыми будет выбираться. То выберется всё нормально, но в таком случае запросу становится наплевать на все остальные параметры. То есть если я задам даты: `DATA_START` и `DATA_END` и ещё например номер трубы `pipe_number` то запрос делает всё ту же выборку и по дате и не смотрит на номер трубы. В чём у меня проблема? подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Или же опишите конкретнее какую выборку вам нужнос делать, зачем такое кол-во `or is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно не смотрит!

```
(da.pipe_number = :p_n or :p_n1 is null) and
(da.pipe_year = :p_e or :p_e1 is null)
```

уберите `or is null` во всех условиях и будет смотреть!